# ElementTree: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I have xml data that wrapped in string, xml data look like this:

```
<Root>
   <Header>
      <information>info</information>
   </Header>
   <Main>
      <Product>
         <Name>name1</Name>
         <Description>description1</Description>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>name2</Name>
         <Description>description2</Description>
      </Product>
   </Main>
</Root>
```

I want delete `Header` tag from it

```
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
tree.remove(tree.findall('.//Header'))
```

But it rise error `list.remove(x): x not in list`. What i did wrong. Thank you

Comment: It seems `tree.remove` takes an element, not a list of elements, which is what `tree.findall` returns. Have you tried calling `tree.remove` for every header you find?

Comment: It returns `Header` tag and than delete it, as i understand from documentation. value `tree` hold xml data that was loaded using `fromstring ` function

Comment: @Wander Nauta No i didn't try to do it because there is only one element `Header`, i'll try to do it

Comment: @WanderNauta I just checked and you're indeed right. Might as well convert the comment to an answer.

Comment: @Reti43 Done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tree.remove` takes a single element, not a list of elements, which is what `tree.findall` returns. You can either call `tree.remove` for every header you find, or just use `tree.find` instead of `tree.findall` if there's only ever going to be one `Header`.

Comment: In addition to this answer, for those (like me) who missed the subtle note about "remove" function only working on the parent element! ie. if you are trying to delete a "Product" element, then you have to do tree.find('./Main).remove('Product')